# AngularJS & $stateParams to display item detail page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat

I apologize if this has been answered somewhere else, but I cannot seem to get my mind wrapped around this and after hours of banging my head, its time to post.

I have a simple list of items coming from Parse.com to populate the list page. I would like to hyperlink the list items to a details page that is specific to that individual item; a page to view all details about the item.

**My Simple Controller** (a basic function that looks at my service to connect to Parse and a custom filter to filter the items for the page)

```
.controller('ProductCtrl',['$scope','$stateParams','Product',function($scope,$stateParams,Product) {
        Product.getAll().success(function(data){
            $scope.items=data.results;
        });

        $scope.filterFn = function(streetBreakfast)
        {
            return(streetBreakfast.segmentStreet === 1) && (streetBreakfast.productCategory === 'Breakfast');
        };
    }])
```

**My Routes** (reduce for brevity)

```
.state('streetBreakfast', {
    url: '/street/breakfast',
    templateUrl: 'views/street-breakfast.html',
    controller: 'ProductCtrl'
})
.state('streetBreakfastDetail', {
    url: '/street/breakfast/:itemId',
    templateUrl: 'views/street-breakfast-detail.html',
    controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
    $scope.itemId = $stateParams.itemId;
    }
})
```

**My HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="col-img-page-2 street"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="item in items | filter:filterFn | orderBy:'productType'" style="padding: 0 0 20px 0">
                <div style="width:100px; height: 100px; margin-bottom: 10px; background: #f7f7f7 url('../images/products/{{ item.productImage }}') no-repeat; background-size: contain"></div>
                <strong>Item#: </strong><a ui-sref="streetBreakfastDetail">{{ item.itemName }}</a><br>
                <strong>Type: </strong>{{ item.productType }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know this has to be an easy answer, but at this point I just need a hand. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID has to be passed when using `ui-sref`:

Plunker Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/phRgzfEBQEn5W0m7JLOB?p=preview

`<strong>Item#: </strong><a ui-sref="streetBreakfastDetail({itemId: item.id })">{{ item.itemName }}</a><br>`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same controller for list and detail, but you are only implementing the list behaviour on it.

You should do something like this (*not tested*):

```
.controller('ProductCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$stateParams',
    'Product',

    function($scope, $stateParams, Product) {
        var itemId = $stateParams.item;

        if (itemId) {
            Product.getItem(itemId).success(function(data){
                $scope.myItem=data.results;
            });
        } else {
            Product.getAll().success(function(data){
                $scope.items=data.results;
            });

            $scope.filterFn = function(streetBreakfast)
            {
                return(streetBreakfast.segmentStreet === 1) && (streetBreakfast.productCategory === 'Breakfast');
            };
        }
    }]);
```

As I said, this is not tested :)

This is a very simple controller, but if you are thinking on implement more logic on it, you should probably think on separate it in two controllers, one for the list and one for the detail.

**EDIT**

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/dmbpVj5s3coMl9JXhUD4?p=preview) you have a copy of your plunkr fixed. You had two problems:

- You weren't passing the argument in `ui-sref` directive, like this: `ui-sref="listDetail({Id: friend.id})"`
- In your controller you had a function called `list` that you weren't calling anywhere.

Comment: Thank you but I am having no luck.  I went through a lot of documentation and changed my question above to reflect what I've done according to tutorials I've read....my brain is about to explode :)  By looking at the new changes, particularly the routes; do you have any ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: Here is a Plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/Ytx99gV4maAkEfc0oKiT?p=preview  - I didn't connect it to our Parse account, but instead setup dummy data in the controller.  Basically it works now exactly the way it works/doesn't in my app - it will route to the detail page but not display any of the details

Comment: Take a look to ui-sref directive, you are missing the parameters for your state: `ui-sref="streetBreakfastDetail({id: 1})"` for example. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref I am writing from the phone now, tomorrow I'll modify your plunkr.

Comment: @StudioRoster I have edited my answer adding a link to your plunkr fixed, and a brief explanation.